# How to ensure, that firewall does not pass any external packets into LAN?

Tags: nat, sniffing

Am I correct thinking, that in the case of NAT and correct firewall config, one should see no any packages with "source address" equals to global IP inside the LAN?

Or NAT server will keep source address while translating?

I am observing multiple packages inside LAN from "source address" pointing to global IPs. Does this mean firewall is setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

NAT doesn’t necessarily mean it’s performed on all interfaces. It could, but on consumer routers there’s usually just two types of translations (simplified):

- Replace source address on outgoing packets with router’s external address
- Replace destination address on incoming packets with actual destination’s internal address (if it’s a related packet)

That means the actual recipient does indeed see that packets are coming from an external source.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then how to ensure, packets are not going via firewall?

Comment: They just don’t. It’s how NAT works. Unless it’s a related packets (outbound first) or a matching port forwarding exists, all inbound packets are discarded.